# Coq: Notation not importing from List

Tags: coq

The title is pretty self-explanatory.
I want to use the standard `[]` and `++` notations for lists. But they go unrecognized even after importing. See the following code.

```
Require Import List.
Check [1].
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Syntax error: [constr:lconstr] expected after 'Check' (in [vernac:query_command]).
```

So basically the notation is not being recognized as a valid constructor.
By contrast, I am able to use `||` from Bool.

I'm stumped. Please save me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The list notations are hidden in two layers of modules:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.
Check [1].
```